# Countifs in google sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, countif

I have problem with using `COUNTIF` in a formula,

I have three columns: `O` with values Yes, `AE` with values returning self-serve, self-serve and assisted and `AH` with dates.

I need to count based on each date users that have yes in column `O` and having only returning self-serve and self-serve in column `AE` (exclude those with value assisted). I tried to this formula:

`=IF(OR(AND('New Self Serve'!AE:AE="new self-serve",'New Self Serve'!O:O="yes"),AND('New Self Serve'!AE:AE="returning self-serve",'New Self Serve'!O:O="yes")),countifs('New Self Serve'!AH:AH,A597))`
but it doesn't work properly and returns values FALSE.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the functions work the same in Excel and GoogleSheets? Please make sure you tag the software you are using.

Comment: I'm using google sheet excel

Comment: So, still not clear. Excel OR Google sheets? Ahh, ok now you have removed the Excel tag.

Comment: using google sheet

Comment: Would you mind sharing a copy of the Sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> I need to count **based on each date** users that **have yes** in column O **and** having only returning **self-serve** and self-serve in column AE (exclude those with value assisted).

You could use a query instead

```
=QUERY(O2:AH17,"select count(O) where AE contains 'self-serve' and O='yes' group by AH label count(O) 'COUNTED'")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)